# How to increase the length of a post Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post

I'm building an application that can display datasets. I imported a larger dataset and got this error: `error: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data?`. I checked out the post Ajax response and found out that it's not displaying the full length of data file that needs to be converted to the JSON. So when I want to select all from that particular (large) dataset it's throwing the error. Is there any way to increase the length of the data(array) file?

This is how my post Ajax data response ends at the moment:

```
 ;, , , , , , , , , , 8400, , 01060000204071000001000000010300000001000000050000008B6CE7FB45F50D416F128300FA412241F2D24D621FF50D41BA490C0207422241560E2DB238F50D41105839B40B422241AAF1D24D5FF50D41333333B3FE4122418B6CE7FB45F50D416F128300FA412241, , 2012, , 0, {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[6.745404,53.363121],[6.745334,53.36318],[6.745382,53.363201],[6.745453,53.363142],[6.745404,53.363121]]]]}, ;, , , , , , , , , , 8402
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to be a valid JSON. Have you validated your JSON response that is coming from server?

Comment: @L.Grunn When you see that JSON response, don't you think there's something pretty off? I don't know how you'd expect a JSON interpreter to be able to use that.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake explaining myself. The data in my example comes from AJAX post. The data is an array of values that gets converted in my code to a JSON. But because I can't get the whole data from the AJAX post call, I can't convert them to JSON. All my other datasets work fine so it has to be something with the length. I will update ny question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Apparently I had some records in my dataset that had no geometry defined. That's why I got the error and my code wasn't working.